# How to know if the zip file is ready to be unzipped after pushing it with adb

Tags: android, file, unzip

I want to push a zip file to my android device using `adb push myfile.zip /data/` and then to programmatically unzip it in my app.

Is there a way to make sure myfile.zip has finished downloading into /data/ before I unzip it?

```
File file = new File("/data/myfile.zip");               
if(file.exists())
    unzip();
```

This will show me that the file exists as soon as it is created but if the zip file is very large it might start unzipping even before it finished downloading.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should first telll us how you are downloading the file. This makes no sense.

Comment: As I wrote: I am doing from the command line `adb push myfile.zip /data/` while my app is running, and I want to unzip it programmatically from my app but only after the `push` command has finished pushing the file into /data/

Comment: Please then do not use the word downloading in the subject. You see that the poster of the answer was confused too. Better put `pushing with adb` in it.

Comment: I thought the body of the message will suffice. I've changed the title for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to monitor the /data/ directory, listen for [CLOSE_WRITE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html#CLOSE_WRITE) events and ensure that the file triggering the event is the one you are interested in :

```
FileObserver dataDirObserver = new FileObserver("/data/", FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE){
    public void onEvent(int event, String path){
        if("/data/myfile.zip".equals(path)){
             unzip();
        }
    }
};


//don't forget to start/stop watching at some point.
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   dataDirObserver.stopWatching(); 
}
public void onResume(){
   super.onPause();
   dataDirObserver.startWatching(); 
}
```

Comment: According to the developer guide, CLOSE_WRITE is triggered when someone had a file or directory open for writing, and closed it. Will it be triggered when the pushing of the file is done without opening it?

Comment: Why do you think adb can be able to push a file in some directory without "open for writing" before ? Every process must "open for writing" before writing a bit on the filesystem. (IMO, the only way to miss the event is if the partition with /data/ is mounted on your computer and unavailable for android)

Comment: So I've tested this method and it is working fine if I push my zip into /data/data/com.example.myapp for example but not working at all when I push the zip into /data/ . Any idea why?

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, could somebody please help me solve this? It seems that my app (which is a launcher) doesn't monitor any changes in the file but when I've tested it in a test app I wrote it worked.... please advise...

Comment: To be able to monitor the /data/ directory : you must have a rooted device

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you are downloading it you can get the size and then compare it.

For example,

```
int count completed;
  try {
        URL url = new URL(this.link);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                8192);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(this.savedFileName);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            completed+=count;
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
```

In the above code the total size would be represented as completed, in bytes. You can compare that to the size of the file prior to unzip by using File.size()

Likewise you can make an object to encapsulate the download item. And create a method like isCompleted()

Comment: I am downloading the file using the command line `adb push myfile.zip /data/` while my app is running and I have no way to know what is the total size of the file.